# python, numpy: Setting the values for an entire 2D plane of a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to store the pixel brightness values of several images in a 3D array, but am unsure how to set the values of an entire 'plane' of the 3D 'cube' in one go. Here's my attempt:

```
imag = Image.open(imagArray[i])
imagPix[:,:,i] = self.getPixelValues(imag)
```

imagArray is an array of filepaths for images stored on the local computer and imagPix is the 3D array of pixel values. imagPix is initially defined as:

```
imagPix = np.zeros((width, height, lenImagArray))
```

where width and height are the dimensions of the image and lenImagArray is the number of images to be saved in the array (in this case 3). I have tried the imagPix[:,:,i] line with '0:' and ':' operators to no avail.

The specific error I receive is:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (640, 480, 3) into shape (640, 480)
```

The getPixelValues method returns a 2D array of pixel brightness values. Code for this is below:

```
def getPixelValues(self, pixImg): ## pixImg is the location of the image, not the image itself
    ## open image and convert to rgb
    imag = Image.open(str(pixImg))
    imag = imag.convert('RGB')

    ## get size of image
    width, height = imag.size

    pixData = list(imag.getdata())
    pixData = [pixData[i * width:(i+1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]
    ## close image and return pixel array
    imag.close()
    return pixData
```

Do I have to use a for loop instead of setting all the values in one go?
Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT:

Now that my problems with getdata() returning a tuple have been fixed I've run into a new problem when using numpy.mean():

```
pixData = np.array(imag.getdata())
pixData = [pixData[i * width:(i+1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]
pixData = np.mean(pixData, 2)
```

This give me the error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (480, 640) into shape (640, 480)

So the dimensions of my array have been 'rotated' for no discernible reason.

Comment: What is in `imagPix` before you do this?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a 3D array of zeros. I'll update the post with the appropriate code.

Comment: Are its first two dimensions the same as the dimensions of your image? And: *What actually goes wrong* when you try to do this? (Do you get an error message? Nothing happening? Corrupted data? Angry monkeys flying out of your computer screen and attacking you?)

Comment: Yes, the first two dimensions are the same as the image. Oh yeah sorry, I've updated the code to include the error message.

Comment: Oh, I think it's because imag.getdata() returns RGB values for each pixel and would therefore be a 3D array and not a 2D one.

Comment: I was just in the process of writing an answer saying that!

Comment: Shall I finish, or would you prefer to write your own answer?

Comment: (I finished it anyway. Feel free to write and accept your own if you like it better.)

Comment: I don't see the point to the `list(imag.getdata())` statement.  `getdata()` probably returns a 3d array (640,480,3), image size plus 3 color bytes.  `list()` turns it into a list of 2d arrays (480,3) each.  You could iterate on the 1st dimension in the next line without the list conversion.

Comment: I've changed that statement so that it stores it in a numpy array (see edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to assign a 3-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional slice. What happens is:

- `imag.getdata()` returns a sequence of pixel values. Those pixel values are actually (R,G,B) tuples.
- So `list(imag.getdata())` is a list of tuples.
- So `pixData` after the manipulation inside `getPixelValues` is a list of lists of tuples.
- So when you try to assign this to a numpy array slice, it's treated as a 3-dimensional array.

What you need to do about this will depend on what you actually want to happen. As it stands, your `imagPix` array is clearly intended to be a 3-dimensional stack of *2-dimensional* (greyscale) images. So you could convert your 3-dimensional image to 2 dimensions in some appropriate way. (It might be enough just to pull out one slice of it, or you might want to take some sort of weighted average of the colour planes, or something.)

Alternatively, perhaps you actually want `imagPix` to be a 4-dimensional stack of 3-dimensional images.

Or perhaps whatever process creates those images should be creating explicitly-greyscale ones, and `getPixelValues` shouldn't be converting them to RGB at all.

Comment: Thank you for answering and apologies for stealing your thunder! I was thinking as you were writing your answer that I could average the three RGB values and then use those. I've rewritten my code to take advantage of np.mean() to average the values in the z-dimension of the cube. Now I've run into the problem of my array dimensions being mysteriously changed whilst the mean is being calculated. I'll update my post so you can see.